# Navigation with React-router to subpage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to make a web application with ReactJs and it works fine. Only now I am getting started with the navigation. The main pages are going well eg localhost: 3000 / dashboard, it displays the relevant view well.

Only now I am trying to create subpages. I thought that I could indicate the following in the routes: `/dashboard/app-overview`.

The problem is that he then places the view from dashboard on the page first and then the view from app overview. I would of course only like to see the view of app-overview but the url is `/dashboard/app-overview`.

My routes.js looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// Layout Types
import { DefaultLayout, ModalLayout } from "./layouts";


import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";

import AppOverviewScreen from "./views/AppOverviewScreen";


export default [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    layout: ModalLayout,
    component: () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: Dashboard,

  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard/app-overview",
    layout: DefaultLayout,
    component: AppOverviewScreen
  },  
];
```

And my `/ dashboard / app-overview` overview as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error, as you can see in my routes.js the values 'exact' have not been entered at the paths. This must be set to `true` for both `/dashboard` and `/dashboard/app-overview`

The right code is:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    
    // Layout Types
    import { DefaultLayout, ModalLayout } from "./layouts";
    
    
    import Dashboard from "./views/Dashboard";
    
    import AppOverviewScreen from "./views/AppOverviewScreen";
    
    
    export default [
      {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        layout: ModalLayout,
        component: () => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
      },
      {
        exact: true,
        path: "/dashboard",
        layout: DefaultLayout,
        component: Dashboard,
    
      },
      {
        exact: true,
        path: "/dashboard/app-overview",
        layout: DefaultLayout,
        component: AppOverviewScreen
      },  
    ]

;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Router exact path instead of just path if you're having path with a similar part in it.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already use the exact path in my app.js

Answer (score 0):

In my program i don't write the route.js like your way but like this:

```
  import AppOverviewScreen from "./views/AppOverviewScreen";
  import {BrowserRouter, Switch,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

  function YourRoute() {
     return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div classname="yourcss">
                <Switch>
                   <Route path="/dashboard/app-overview" component={AppOverviewScreen} exact/>
                </Switch>
                </div>
             </BrowserRouter>
      );
   }
```

Like this i don't have your problem. Don't know if this helps you